# Summing XML attributes sometimes returns zero

Tags: c#, xml, .net-3.5, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to parse an NZB file (which is XML) and sum the bytes attributes.  Sometimes it works perfectly and sometimes it returns zero, and I can't figure out why.  The NZB files have identical structure as far as I can tell.

```
private Int32 processNZB(string sFilename)
{
    XDocument xFile = XDocument.Load(sFilename);

    Int32 sum = xFile.Descendants("segment").Sum(x => (int)x.Attribute("bytes"));

    sum = (int)(sum / 1024 / 1024); // bytes -> MB
    return sum;
}
```

Source code and sample files can be found here: http://jonathanslaven.com/.for/.stackoverflow/

Is there an obvious reason this isn't working?  Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: it isn't necessary to put C# in the title.  That is what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the initial value of sum is less than 1024<sup>2</sup> bytes? As you are performing integer division, the result will be trucated, so anything less than 1024<sup>2</sup> bytes will return zero.

For instance, the [example NZB file @ wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NZB) would give 0 when run through your algorithm.

EDIT:

Upon inspection of the "bad" files (actually, it's the "good" one that isn't following the spec), the reason it's not working is that the default namespace of the root element is `"http://www.newzbin.com/DTD/2003/nzb"` meaning any child nodes will inherit this namespace.

This means that your query `.Descendants("segment")` returns no nodes. Attaching the correct namespace fixes the problem.

The following shows how you might modify your code to read such a file.

```
private int ProcessNzb(string sFilename)
{
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(sFilename);
    return xDoc
        .Descendants(xDoc.Root.Name.Namespace + "segment")
        .Sum(x => (int) x.Attribute("bytes")) / 1024 / 1024;
}
```

As an aside, I'd avoid posting files that suggest involvement in contraband.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, that did the trick.  This is the first time I've ever played around with XML files.

(PS: no contraband, all tv shows on channels i subscribe to)

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that the sum is small enough to be rounded to 0 when dividing by 1024 using integer division?

An example:

```
int sum = 300; //300
int sumDividedOnce = sum/1024; // 0
int sumDividedTwice = sumDividedOnce/1024; // 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - no, it's the same if i comment that line out and return bytes instead of megabytes

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you change

```
Int32 sum = xFile.Descendants("segment").Sum(x => (int)x.Attribute("bytes"));
```

to

```
Int32 sum = xFile.Descendants("segment").Sum(x => int.Parse(x.Attribute("bytes").Value));
```

Comment: The explicit conversion operator on `XAttribute` to `int` does virtually the same thing as your alternative.